# passing a model to a method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, models

In refactoring, I need to move a `generate_token` method out of my user model so that it can be called by other models.

This is the method code:

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

Where the column is passed in allowing the user model to generate many different tokens as needed.  The method is called like:

```
def some_other_method
  generate_token(:token_column_name)
  ...
end
```

My user model currently passes in two different token columns to the method: `auth_token` and `pw_reset_token`.

My first thought is to put it in the `/lib/generate_token.rb` and call it from the model with `include generate_token`.  I shouldn't have to pass in the column param on the include, since it is just including the method, not calling it.

The challenge for me is the `end while User.exists?(column => self[column])`.  This prevents the method from generating a new token if one already exists.  However, this is assuming the User Model; instead I need to refactor it to take the model that is calling the method, and passing that in as a variable to the method, like:

`include generate_token(model_name)`

so that the code can now read

`end while [Model].exists?(column => self[column])`

Is this possible?  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a library class is the way to go here, or more specifically, a Rails [Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) (same diff in this context).

That said, you can call `self.class` to get the class, then do things like `self.class.exists?`

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.  I'll  post my code as soon as I get it working.

(or, I'll post on the Stack again... :p)

Comment: Great, glad I could help.